# How to disable Hybris cache?

Tags: caching, sap-commerce-cloud

In develop mode, I would like to disable the Hybris cache regions (at least the query region). I found no property for this in the project.properties and any information in the Hybris official website.

Comment: Did you try min cache size?

Answer (score 0):

By default Hybris use Region Cache. You can disable Region cache but then Hybris will use the previous cache solution.

local.properties

> cache.legacymode=true

It is recommended to use the Hybris Region Cache. That is why after switching to the previous cache solution you can expect some warning messages displayed in the console logs and in the Hybris Administration Console on Cache page.

OR

You can try changing its size to Zero but i am not sure.

Default Value -

```
regioncache.querycacheregion.size=20000
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways explained here : [Region cache](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8c392bd686691014ae1bf4af383a81d5.html)

Quoting the doc :

> Disabling the Hybris Region Cache
>
> The Hybris Region Cache is the default cache. However you can still
>   use the previous cache solution by adding the following parameter to
>   the local.properties file: local.properties cache.legacymode=true
>
> It is recommended to use the Hybris Region Cache. That is why after
>   switching to the previous cache solution you can expect some warning
>   messages displayed in the console logs and in the Hybris
>   Administration Console on Cache page.

Clearing cache by code :

```
CacheRegion region = ...;
region.clearCache();
```

Set a configuration (not tried)

```
regioncache.querycacheregion.size=0
```

Set a JVM property (only for ehcache):

```
-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true
```

Answer (score -1):

You can deactivate cache feature on **SAP Hybris platform** by running below **groovy** script via **HAC** console :

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.Registry;
Registry.getMasterTenant().getCache().setEnabled(false);
```